# Is using "in partnership with" enough to tell Google about sponsored links in an article?

Tags: backlinks, tags, penalty

If you post an article on a website and it says "in partnership with X agency" and that article has a few backlinks to some brands, does Google recognize that this article is 'sponsored' and related to the agency that posted the article, or to the brands that are mentioned in the article?

No html tags were added, so I was wondering could this lead to a penalty to the brands linked?

Comment: Honestly I don't think it works that way. Ranking and disclosure are not related. Not disclosing properly might put you in violation of some agreement or of local laws that should not feed back into rankings.

Comment: I understand this part, my question was more about the possible penalties, not about the rankings. :)

Answer (score 1):

If the links were paid for, I would suggest using the rel="sponsored" attribute on them. If they were not paid for, I would recommend (to you as the webmaster; to the agency I would recommend the opposite) to have a rel="nofollow" attribute.